# Unable to download updates

Tags: permissions, updates, repository

Going to **About this computer > Install updates** I get `Failed to Download Repository information`.

Under **Settings > Software and Updates**, I switched to the main server and tried downloading again, but was given:

```
W:archive.canonical.com/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W:The repository 'ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E:Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've tried running `sudo apt-get update` and I get the same as above.

I've also gotten the error that I don't have enough disk space on `/boot`, so I tried `sudo apt-get clean`, but that didn't seem to do anything. Sudo apt-get autoremove gives me:

"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded."

Any ideas on what I can do?  A few weeks ago, I had a problem where my computer wouldn't connect to the internet after it fell asleep, so I ran some code I found on this site, but I'm not sure what it did or if that's what's causing this issue.

Comment: Try after few minutes.

Comment: The links apt is trying to fetch can't be displayed on the site, can you [edit] your question to add such links just as plain text (without www. nor https://) - Refering to the last problem, run `sudo apt-get clean` or `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

Comment: @M. Becerra Sudo apt-get autoremove removed a few things.  I tried sudo apt-get update afterwards, but still ran into the same problem. sudo apt-get clean didn't seem to do much of anything.

I also edited the error message from earlier and added the plain text links.

Comment: @karel I forgot to use sudo when I first ran "clean" and "autoremove".  Even when I run those, I still can't manage to get my computer to download updates.